# Vue use ref: TypeError: Cannot write private member xxx to an object whose class did not declare it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a class `outer`, and a member variable `inner` of this class is also a class. This variable `inner` has a private attribute `name` and a function `getName` that operates on private attributes. When I wrap the outer with `ref`, I cannot access the name using `outer.inner.getName()`.Following is my code:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'
class Outer {
    inner: Inner = new Inner('aaa')
    getInnerName() {
        return this.inner.getName()
    }
}
class Inner {
    #name: string
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.#name = name
    }
    getName() {
        return this.#name
    }
}
const outer = ref(new Outer())
console.log(outer.value.getInnerName())
```

A error happens:`TypeError: Cannot read private member #name from an object whose class did not declare it`
Why it happens and how to fix it? The inner class is a third party library, so I can only adjust the outer

Comment: Out of interest, does it work if you don't make `outer` a `ref` ... i.e. `const outer = new Outer(); console.log(outer.getInnerName())`

Comment: @jaromanda-x it works well without ref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all answer！
i solve it using `markRaw` provided by vue.
Like this:

```js
import { ref,markRaw } from 'vue'
class Outer {
    inner: Raw<Inner> = markRaw(new Inner('aaa'))
    getInnerName() {
        return this.inner.getName()
    }
}
class Inner {
    #name: string
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.#name = name
    }
    getName() {
        return this.#name
    }
}
const outer = ref(new Outer())
console.log(outer.value.getInnerName())
```

This func will mark the attribute can't be `ref` and when use `ref(new Outer())`, inner won't be influenced. You can't tracking the variation of inner, but fortunately i don't need to track it.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the method on the constructor if you like. Here's an example:

```
this.getName = this.getName.bind(this)
```

So, your full example would be like this:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
class Outer {
    inner = new Inner('aaa')
    getInnerName() {
        return this.inner.getName()
    }
}
class Inner {
    #name
    constructor(name) {
        this.#name = name
        this.getName = this.getName.bind(this)
    }
    getName() {
        return this.#name
    }
}
const outer = ref(new Outer())
console.log(outer.value.getInnerName())
```

Sorry, i remove the type

edit 1:

I tried using proxy to access the object value like this:

```
const p = new Outer();
const proxy = new Proxy(p, {
    get: (target, prop, receiver) => {
        return target[prop];
    }
});
```

And tried to access it like this:

```
const outer = ref(new Outer())
const a = ref(proxy.getInnerName())
console.log(a) /// aaa
```

Without no problem. So you can try it